# Using rbind with do.call returns unexpected character matrix size

Tags: r

I have a list of character matrices generated by str_match_all from the stringr package. I'm using do.call(rbind, d1) to make the list into one large matrix. However, the resulting large matrix has fewer rows than what was present in the list of matrices. Why would that happen? This is my code:

```
d1 <- str_match_all(as.character(d$variable), 
"([a-z]+)([0-9]{4})\\.(SQ\\d{3})_(SQ\\d{3})\\."
)

d2 <- do.call(rbind, d1)
```

- d1 is a list of 39798 1x5 character matrices
- d2 is a 35208 x 5 matrix

If I understand the way do.call and rbind work, I should end up with a matrix that is 39798 x 5. No?

`d$variable` is a string vector which contains multiple descriptors in each element that I want to separate out into their own columns (e.g., aac2012.SQ001_SQ001. --> aac 2012 SQ001 SQ001)

Comment: It will likely be hard to offer much help without a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the rbind function seems to drop rows that have an inconsistent number of columns.
str_match_all can return a zero length vector on a no-match

```
# How many rows had an inconsistent match-length? 39798 minus 35208 ?
sum(sapply(d1, length) != 5) 
# Show the input strings that did not produce a length 5 output vector:
d$variable[sapply(d1, length) != 5]
```

Comment: Perfect. As you suspected there were certain elements that were not matched that created the mismatch.